# Gremlin reverse traversal

Tags: gremlin, graph-traversal

In a Gremlin graphdb I have something like:

```
root
   level1
      level2
        levelN
```

If I know 'root' I can find 'levelN' using the following query:

```
g.v().has('name','root').repeat(out().simplePath()).until(has('name','levelN'))
```

but how do I go the other way, given I know 'levelN', how do I find 'root' it doesn't seem to be possible to do:

```
g.v().has('name','levelN').repeat(in().simplePath()).until(has('name','root'))
```

TIA

/Søren

Comment: Can you elaborate on "doesn't seem possible"? The traversal looks good to me, there's only a minor issue, which I consider to be a typo (`v()` should be `V()`).

Comment: I'm using the Graph part of Azure CosmosDb and if I'm running the statement:

g.V().has('name','Level3').repeat(in().simplePath()).until(has('name','Root'))

on a four node graph (hierarchy), I get the error:

Failure in submitting query: g.V().has('name','Level3').repeat(in().simplePath()).until(has('name','Root'))
...
Query Syntax Error: Script compile error: Missing ')'

Comment: If I change my query to:
g.V().has('name','Level3').repeat(inE().otherV().simplePath()).until(has('name','Root'))
it seems to work

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the client language you are using, `in` is a reserved word and should be written as `__.in()` or `in_()`.

Check Vertex Steps in the TinkerPop documentation for more information:
http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#vertex-steps